# Does a black screen save battery on a macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop, power-management

I've seen some similar questions about iPhone on this site, but none of them focus on macbook, so here comes this one.

The picture below is a screenshot of my current desktop, with menu bar and dock hidden, as well as grey scale turned on.

[image]

Can some pattern (black specifically) save enough energy on a macbook that you’d get more than 5 minutes runtime in a full battery to discharge cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. No battery will be saved regardless of what color your screen is. This only applies when the screen is OLED, like in the Apple Watch.

You can save battery by lowering the screen brightness, though.

Answer (score 1):

No battery will be saved regardless of what color your screen is - agreed. however, personally, although, I prefer white text on black background, I feel more comfortable at lower brightness with black text on white background

Answer (score 0):

> Can doing so save some energy on a macbook?

No.

> Approximately how much energy can be saved?

None

> Conversely, what if I have a plain white(#FFFFFF) desktop picture?

It makes no difference. No energy will be saved. Your energy depends on screen brightness, not color.